# GGPlot side by side graphs shiny dashboard

Tags: ggplot2

I want to make my ggplots sit side by side. I've adjusted the size for some of the graphs, their sizes adjusted but my intention was to put them side by side.

The code is written below for ui.r

```
        tabPanel("Scores scores",
                         tabsetPanel("tab",
                                    tabPanel("Score Summary",
                                       selectInput("Num","Select the variable",choices = c("Score scores"=14, "Customer experience score"= 20, "Business experience score" = 21, "Legal experience score" = 22)),
                                       column(width= 12, p("This plot visualizes the number of Nos for each experience")),
                                       sliderInput("bins","Select the BINS of the histgram",min=5, max= 15, value = 10),
                                       plotOutput("myhist"),
                                       selectInput("qt","Select the variable",choices = c("Question 1"=23)),
                                       tableOutput("aud")),
                                    tabPanel("Survey question",
                                             plotOutput("aa",height=200,width=350),
                                             plotOutput("ab",height=200,width=350),
                                             plotOutput("ac",height=200,width=350),
                                             plotOutput("ad",height=200,width=350),
                                             plotOutput("ae"),
                                             plotOutput("af"),
                                             plotOutput("ag"),
                                             plotOutput("ah"),
                                             plotOutput("ai"),
                                             plotOutput("aj"),
                                             plotOutput("ak"),
                                             plotOutput("al"),
                                             plotOutput("am"),
                                             plotOutput("an"),
                                             plotOutput("ao")
                                    )
                                    ))
```

The screenshot of my dashboard is here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHPNy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the package `gridExtra` and its command `grid.arrange`? See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html for more. In your case `grid.arrange(gg1, gg2, gg3, ..., nrow=1)` might be the way to go.